# How to look at the covariant derivative along a curve?

Tags: definition, riemannian-geometry, curves, connections

Let $ \Gamma(M,TM) $ be the space of smooth sections from $M$ to $TM$ and $ (M,g) $ be a Riemannian manifold, $ I \subset \mathbb{R} $ be an interval and $\gamma: I \rightarrow M$ be a $C^1$ curve. Let $ \nabla: \Gamma(M,TM) \times \Gamma(M,TM) \rightarrow \Gamma(M,TM) $ be the Levi-Civita connection with respect to $(M,g)$. Then since $ \dot{\gamma} : I \rightarrow TM $ is not an element of $ \Gamma(M,TM) $ but an element of $ \Gamma(I, TM) $. What is the proper way for one to interpret notations like $ \nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}X $ or $ \nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma} $?

Comment: My understanding is that the resulting section does not depend on the way you choose to extend the vector field to the rest of $M$.

Comment: I think it is not always possible that you can extend this vector field. Given the operator $ D/dt $ along $\gamma$ which takes $ \Gamma( I, TM ) \rightarrow \Gamma(I, TM) $ people seems to write $ D/dt = \nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} $ without much explanation. But then stress that $ D/dt $ is the way to do thing. This is what confuses me.

Comment: Just sharing an opinion: In order to have a geometrical interpretation, I think higher dimensional geometry is very complicated in nature so we should take it to two or three dimensional to visualize.

Comment: Are you asking for formal interpretation? Like, connection is defined so that it takes two vector fields on $M$ as input, but the notations $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}X$ or $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}$ do not exactly take two vector fields on $M$ as input, and you want to understand how these two objects are defined formally?

Comment: Yes, this is just a matter of definition. So I would like to understand the formal way to look at this,

Comment: Do you have any book on Riemannian geometry which you have on hand or will be able to access?

Comment: I use the book by Lafontaine. However if there is a PDF version of the book then I should be able to access it via the school library.

Comment: Is $X$ a vector field on $M$ or a vector field on the curve $\gamma$?

Comment: I putted X there to mean anything that could possibly make sense to there, be it defined on $I$ or $M$. However at this stage it seems like it should be a vector field defined along $\gamma$ (for it to make sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *proper* way to do this is to pull back the bundle $E\to M$ (in this case $E=TM$ but this works in general) and its connection to $I$:
$$
\gamma^*\nabla\colon\Gamma(\gamma^*E)\to\Gamma(\gamma^*E\otimes T^*I);\\(\gamma^*\nabla)_X(\gamma^*s)=\gamma^*(\nabla_{(d\gamma)(X)}s)\quad\forall s\in\Gamma(E),\forall X\in TI
$$
and so $\frac{D}{dt}\dot\gamma:=(\gamma^*\nabla)_{d/dt}\dot\gamma$ (and suchlikes) makes sense.  But that is rather a lot of $\gamma$'s lying around.

Let $[\gamma]=\{\gamma(t)\mid t\in I\}$.  If $X\in\Gamma(I,E)$ is such that $X$ comes from $[\gamma]\to E$ (i.e., if $\gamma(t)=\gamma(t')$ then $X(t)=X(t')$), then we can always extend $X$ to some $\tilde{X}$ in a neighbourhood $U$ of $[\gamma]$ when $E,M$ are finite-dimensional (for infinite-dimensional case there are some complications), being at least as smooth as the original data $(\gamma,X)$ (this is basically the Whitney extension theorem).  We can now ask the question: is $\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\tilde{X}$ the same as $(\gamma^*\nabla)_{d/dt} X$?  The answer is yes (as you know), so we can write $\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma$ (and suchlikes).

Comment: Can we always make sure we can extend $ \dot{\gamma} $ to a neighbourhood around the image of $\gamma$? Is there a canonical way to do this? So that $ ({\gamma}^{\ast} \nabla)_{\dot{\gamma}} {\dot{\gamma}} = \nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma} =  \frac{D}{dt} \dot{\gamma} $ is always unambiguous. Sorry I'm pretty new to Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Sorry I noticed my mistake. $ \dot{\gamma} $ can certainly be extended. On the other hand, is there a concrete way to write down this extension?

Comment: For "nice" $\dot\gamma$ (e.g., $\gamma$ is an embedding) you can pick a tubular neighbourhood of $[\gamma]$, on which you have $\dot\gamma=\partial_1$.  It is pretty clear how to extend.  For less nice $\gamma$, you need to be lucky to write down an explicit extension.