# Proper Way to view vector field component functions with respect to covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I follow this lecture  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eVWUdcI2ho&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_&index=8 and at minute 35, the covariant derivative is used to calculate the geodesic equation. The lecturer says, that the term to calculate the second derivative is strictly not defined. He is right, because Gamme dot q, is a function from R to R and not from M to R. So the partial operator is not defined. How does he calculate the second derivative and how to make sense out this. Is it better to think of the vector field component functions as function from M to R? In the lecture they are functions from R to R. Iam grateful for any help!

Comment: See [Clarifying the definition of the directional derivative of a curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4152468/568204) for the situation in $\Bbb{R}^n$. The idea is that the covariant derivative doesn't actually use the full information of vector fields. It only requires information along certain directions. See the mentioned reference to Lee's book; Do Carmo's book also talks about this (there he denotes this operation as $\frac{D}{dt}$ when taking covariant derivatives along curves).

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990093/how-to-look-at-the-covariant-derivative-along-a-curve But I do not fully understand what to pull-back from TM.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that although $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^m}\dot\gamma^n$ doesn't exist (since $\dot\gamma^n$ is only defined along the curve $\gamma$), the quantity
$$
\left(\dot\gamma^m\frac{\partial}{\partial x^m}\right)\dot\gamma^n
$$
does exist, since it really means
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\dot\gamma^n(\gamma(t)),
$$
i.e. the derivative of $\dot\gamma^n$ along the curve $\gamma$. And this latter is just $\ddot\gamma^n$.

As an alternative way to understand this, it's probably conceptually clearer to say
$$
\nabla_{v_\gamma}v_\gamma = \nabla_{v_\gamma}\left(\dot\gamma^n\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right) = v_\gamma(\dot\gamma^n)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n} + \dot\gamma^n\nabla_{v_\gamma}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}
$$
and then using $v_\gamma(\dot\gamma^n) = \ddot\gamma^n$ (since $v_\gamma(f) = \dot f$ for any function $f$ by definition).

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue. $v_{\gamma}$ acts on smooth functions $f:M\to\Bbb{R}$, so $v_{\gamma}(\dot{\gamma}^n)$ isn't defined. So, you've just side-stepped one issue for another.

Comment: If you take the definition $v_\gamma(t)(f) = \frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))$, then it makes perfect sense, since $\dot\gamma^n$ is defined along the curve $\gamma$. I suppose strictly speaking one would need to argue that the derivation property $\nabla_{v_x}(f w) = (v_xf)w + f \nabla_{v_x}w$ still holds when $f$ is only defined along curves with $v_x$ as a tangent. It's a matter of taste whether mine is an acceptable explanation, but I was trying to be consistent with the explanation given in the linked video.

Comment: No, again it still doesn't have the correct type. Given smooth $f:M\to\Bbb{R}$ and $\gamma:I\subset \Bbb{R}\to M$, we define $v_{\gamma}(f):= (f\circ \gamma)'(0)$. Now, $\dot{\gamma}^n:I\to\Bbb{R}$, so you just can't plug it into $v_{\gamma}$. The composition $\dot{\gamma}^n\circ \gamma$ doesn't make sense. Sure, everything boils down to the fact that things depend only on what happens along the curve, but the way you've written doesn't properly justify this (also the lecturer says explicitly he's being sloppy due to time). Hence my previous comment that you side-stepped one issue for another.

Comment: Here I'm interpreting $v_\gamma$ as a distributional vector field, i.e. a vector field with support on the image of $\gamma$ only, and correspondingly $\dot\gamma^n:M\to \mathbb{R}$ with support on $\gamma(I)$. Ok, this isn't quite consistent with the lecturer's use of the term, but his definitions are all over the place. If you take my interpretation, and accept that the derivation property also holds for distributional vector fields, then the derivation I gave makes sense, and also it captures the intuition that $\nabla_{v_x}w$ only requires knowledge of $w$ along a curve with tangent $v_x$.

Comment: Maybe one solution could be to interpret the vector component function along the curve gamma as $\partial(x^m \circ \gamma)(\gamma^{-1}(p))$, where $\gamma^{-1}(p) = \lambda$? So you technical to solve the geodesic equation with respect to gamma?